# Can't search plugin in local but on the net when install Plugin with Vundle (configure Vim)

Tags: vim, plugins, vundle

I have successfully installed the Vundle for vim

With the help-docs, i know that using command "PluginInstall **" can install this plugin

i have already download some plugins, but when i type :PluginInstall **
to install ** , it's not install ** from local but again search on the net.

So, how can i specify the path should this command ":PluginInstall" install plugin from where i want.

=======================for example:
:PluginSearch taglist

it shows

Plugin 'taglist-plus'
Plugin 'taglist.vim'

my local file is taglist_46 which download from www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=273‎

but it doesn't show up in result

Comment: If you have a problem with Vundle, better ask on the plugin's issue tracker than here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should add the follow settings in your vimrc:

```
Bundle 'taglist.vim'
```

And then, run `:BundleInstall`, Vundle will download the plugin automatically. (automatic is the important reason to using it)

---

By the way, Vundle using **git** download the plugin, it should be installed.

If you don't have git (In windows for example), you can download by manually of cause. Just move the taglist folder to the *right path*. It was set by `rpt+=<the right path>`. For example, [my setting](https://github.com/Marslo/VimConfig/blob/master/Configurations/vimrc#L44) is:

```
if has('win32') || has('win64')
  set rtp+=$VIM/bundle/vundle
  call vundle#rc('$VIM/bundle')
else
  set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle
  call vundle#rc()
endif
```

Means the *right path* in Windows should be *$VIM/bundle/vundle*, and *~/.vim/bundle/vundle* in Linux